# parse different json file with variable key value pair in same python code

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a folder with many `json` files like below

`sample1.json`:

```
[{
    "TimeField": "UTC",
    "Subject": "",
    "Severity": "Medium",
},
{
    "TimeField": "MDT",
    "Subject": "",
    "Severity": "Medium",
}]
```

`sample2.json`:

```
[{
    "TimeField": "UTC",
    "Subject": "",
    "Severity": "low",
    "Comment" : ""
},
{
    "TimeField": "MDT",
    "Subject": "",
    "Severity": "low",
    "Comment" : ""
}]
```

My code:

```
def get_parameters(obj):

        timefield = obj['TimeField']
        subject = obj['Subject']
        severity = obj['Severity']
        comment = obj['Comment']
        return(timefield ,subject ,severity ,comment )
```

```
try:
   path = "/opt/AAA/aaa"
   for files in os.listdir(path):
    try:
      if files.endswith('.json'):
        json_path = os.path.join(path, files)
        with open(json_path, "r") as json_file:
           json_index = json.load(json_file)
           for obj in json_index:
                parameters = get_parameters(obj)
except Exception as ex:
       DEBUGLOG_OBJ.critical("Exception Line no: {0} : {1} while executing ".format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno, ex))
```

Getting exception due to Comment not in `sample1.json`:

```
CRITICAL - Exception Line no:  : 'Comments' 
How to parse json files with variable number of key value pair
```

Answer (score 2):

The objects in your `json_index` are standard `dict`s, so you can just use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for all optional keys.

```py
def get_parameters(obj):
    
     timefield = obj['TimeField']
     subject = obj['Subject']
     severity = obj['Severity']
     comment = obj.get('Comment')
     return(timefield ,subject ,severity ,comment )
```